# How to get the user entered input value to do calculation?

Tags: 7, search

I am developing bank loan application in drupal 7. In my first page there is a option to enter the `loan amount` then --> `Search` the available loan. In a second page(form) i need to display the available `loan offers, interest, etc`... based on the **user entered value in page-1**. Now i need to get the user entered value on page-2 and have to check with DB(Database) and then needs to display the results. Help me to get out the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Store the loan amount in session when user submit the form1, and when rendering the form take that session value and display a suggestion field.

The code will be like below,

```
function form1_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $_SESSION['loan_search_amount_field_value'] = $form_state['values']['loan_search_amount_field_name'];
}

function form2() {
  $form = array();
  $loan_amount = $_SESSION['loan_search_amount_field_value'];
  //db_query using $loan_amount
  //$db_result_array = db_query();
  $form['load_options'] = array(
    '#description' => t('Loan options'),    
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Field type'),
    '#options' => $db_result_array,
    '#size' => 2,
  );      
  return $form;
}
```